Where to find Moodle v2.2?
In our school we were given the task of updating a Moodle on a Vm to the latest version. v2.0.10 is installed. This is ancient and we should learn how to deal with ancient systems and bring them up to date. Now the Moodle website says that you first have to upgrade to version 2.2 before you can continue. Where can I find this version? I can't download anything here or am I blind?: https://moodledev.io/general/releases/2.2
Tried with 2.4 but had problems with PHP. He said the PHP installed was not compatible. (Although I have 5.4 installed and only 5.3.2 is needed)
References: https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Upgrading_to_Moodle_2.2
https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Upgrading#Using_a_downloaded_archive
Thank you for your help guys!
I tried to upgrade moodle step by step to the newest version. Didn't work. Tried to skip a version, didn't work.
EDIT: Moodle is currently being hosted on Windows Server 2016. Part of the task is also to upgrade to WinSrv2k22, but I decided to go on with Moodle first and the OS later on.

Have you checked the tag on the git repository? (See https://docs.moodle.org/404/en/Git_for_Administrators)

You can download old Moodle branches from Github
Go to https://github.com/moodle/moodle
Click on Branches > All
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/branches/all
Then select MOODLE_22_STABLE
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/MOODLE_22_STABLE
Then click the green <> code button - the drop down menu will give you an option to download the zip
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/archive/refs/heads/MOODLE_22_STABLE.zip
